# Using CORS with Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm doing a WS in c# and calling from a JavaScript.

My service had a problem with CrossDomain, I solved with `jsonp`.

But after that, I needed to change `json` to `xml` because I use soap header to authentication on the WS (I don't know how to use header with json calling from js).

When I change to xml I find out the 3rd problem:

I sent the request with cors header but even when the WS I use allows origins on the `web.config`, doesn't work.

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
```

How can i configure my WS to receive any origin?

PS: I dont have a global.asax because my project is not a Web Site, its a c# project with an asmx.

**My header**

```
public class MyHeader : SoapHeader
    {
        public int Authuser;
        public string hash;

        public bool Auntenticou()
        {
            //Validation
        }
    }
```

**My WS**

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class Classe: System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public MyHeader head{ get; set; }

        [SoapHeader("head")]
        [WebMethod(Description = "methods.")]
        public string Method()
        {

            if (head.Auntenticou())
            {
                //do something
                return "Work";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Error";
            }
     }
```

And The Calling **XML** and **JSON**

```
function callXML(){             
    var url = "http://localhost/service.asmx/Method";
    var soapXML =
       "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8?'>" +
       "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' xmlns:tem='http://tempuri.org/'>"+
        "<soap:Header>"+
            "<tem:MyHeader>"+
                "<tem:Authuser>1</tem:Authuser>"+
                "<tem:hash>12345</tem:hash>"+
            "</tem:MyHeader>"+
        "</soap:Header>"+
        "<soap:Body>"+
            "<tem:Method>"+
                // Parameters
            "</tem:Method>"+
        "</soap:Body>"+
        "</soap:Envelope>";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', 'service.asmx/Method'); },
        dataType: 'xml',
        data: soapXML,
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {

        }
    });
}
```

Call **jsonp** (but I don't know how to put the Header values **"Authuser"** and **"hash"**)

```
function jsonCall(){            
    var url = "http://localhost/service.asmx/Method";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        //contentType: "text/xml",
        contentType: 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,
        //headers: { "SoapHeader": soapXML },
        data: { //jsonvalues 
              },
        success: OnSuccessCall,
        error: OnErrorCall
    });

    function OnSuccessCall(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }

    function OnErrorCall(response) {
        alert(response.status + " " + response.statusText);
    }

}
```

Comment: Setting datatype as jsonp in your Ajax call won't work unless your WS returns jsonp which is different than ordinary json as it includes a call back function.

Comment: i don't know how return jsonp in my WebMethod. i have the [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] and [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)].... dont have the "jsonp" options

Comment: Then use json and try adding the header directly into the response, instead of using web.config.

Comment: but i cant use json rather jsonp because i have the croosdomain call... i only use jsonp because that

Comment: The data type jsonp only exist in a request. From server you return json with the call back e.g. `myFunc({ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York" });`. Where `myFunc` is the callback, that is, the function that is going to be called in Javascript when it gets the response. Using jsonp is not the only way for allowing cross domain access. Adding proper headers in the response should work. See https://amanagrawal.blog/2014/04/18/using-jquery-ajax-to-talk-to-asp-net-asmx-web-services/